# How do i make all buttons stay on the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 buttons in 4 different cards that have different text size, and i need to make button stay on the bottom no matter how much i put text in cards

```
<div class="pricing-block">
 <div class="pricing-cards">
   <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
   <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 3</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 4</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 5</p>
  <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
 </div>
</div>

.pricing-block{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: You either wrap all those list in one container, or apply a height and you simple apply `margin-top:auto;` on the buttons. at your current state, the content defines the height and since there's no empty space, you can't align elements on the `y axis`

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your pricing content in a div and then allowing it to grow (`flex-grow: 1`) will ensure the buttons stay at bottom.

```css
.pricing-block{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.pricing-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pricing-cards-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-block">
  <div class="pricing-cards">
    <div class="pricing-cards-content">
      <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
      <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
      <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
      <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
      <p class="pricing-features">Feature 3</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing-cards">
    <div class="pricing-cards-content">
      <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
      <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
      <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
      <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable content into one div and the buttons into another and then use flex-grow to stretch the variable content. You can set a height on the parent element to allow all the cards to be the same height.

```css
.pricing-block{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.pricing-card {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
  padding: 8px;
 }
 
 .pricing-card-header {
    flex-shrink:0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
 }
 .pricing-card-body {
    flex-grow: 1;
 }
 
  .pricing-card-footer {
    flex-shrink:0;
      padding: 8px;
    border-top: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
 }
```

```html
<div class="pricing-block">
 <div class="pricing-card">
    <div class="pricing-card-header">
      <p class="pricing-description"> <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b> 79$</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pricing-card-body">
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 3</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 4</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 5</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pricing-card-footer">
     <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 
  <div class="pricing-card">
    <div class="pricing-card-header">
     
      <p class="pricing-description"> <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b> 79$</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pricing-card-body">

     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pricing-card-footer">
     <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 
   <div class="pricing-card">
    <div class="pricing-card-header">
     
      <p class="pricing-description"> <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b> 79$</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pricing-card-body">

     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 3</p>
     <p class="pricing-features">Feature 4</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pricing-card-footer">
     <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped but an approach is wrong (in my case) But damn thanks for help a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
Hopefully works for you!
```

link provided which helps you [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/NWpaVGp)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
.pricing-block{
display: flex;
/* flex-wrap: wrap; */ Removed
flex-direction: row;
/* justify-content: space-evenly; */ Removed
}
.pricing-button { display: flex; }
.pricing-cards { margin-left: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="pricing-block">
 <div class="pricing-cards">
   <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
   <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 1</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 2</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 3</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 4</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Feature 5</p>
  <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
 </div><!-- First Card -->
  <div class="pricing-cards">
   <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
   <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
  <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
 </div><!-- Second Card -->
  <div class="pricing-cards">
   <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
   <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
  <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
 </div><!-- Third Card -->
  
  <div class="pricing-cards">
   <b class="pricing-tittle">Unlimited</b>
   <p class="pricing-description">79$</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
   <p class="pricing-features">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
  <button type="button" class="pricing-button">Purchase</button>
 </div><!-- Fourth Card -->
</div>
```